# Isometries of S^3 and some Lie algebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, 3d

By considering $S^3$ as the group of unit quaternions, and letting it act on itself from both the left and right, one can get an isomorphism $SO(4)\cong (S^3\times S^3)/C_2$, where the $C_2$ subgroup is generated by $(-1,-1)$.  This means $SO(4)$ is a two-sheeted covering of $SO(3)\times SO(3)$.  Is there a way to see this covering directly from the exceptional Lie algebra isomorphism $D_2\cong B_1\times B_1$?

Comment: To see that there exists a covering of one by the other, or to see that the covering is $2:1$ and in that direction in particular?

Comment: @Travis: the latter is what I'm most interested in. But feel free to post something about the former as well.